# How to make my script resolve the display name of a mailbox and process it in the script?

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell at work and I'm tasked to remove the office location of a multitude of mailboxes.

Now, I have a basic script that works but the issue is that at the moment running the script will only work when using the "User Logon Name" value. Problem is I cannot export that value from my search results in exchange easily, only the display name, email address or alias and other values that aren't relevant. Most of our mailboxes have an alias that matches the logon name but there is still a significant portion that I cannot do by hand and would need the script to work with the mailbox aliases/display names/SMTPs

```
$Mailboxes = ("".Trim().Split("`n").Trim())

foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes){
Set-ADUser $Mailbox -Office $null -Credential $AdminCredentials
}
```

How can I make my script work to resolve and find mailboxes from the display name or alias or email for example?

I tried looking up other scripts at work and google but I just can't incorporate it no matter what I do. I'm a visual learner as well so if someone could write the script and how it should work it would make meu understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a working script by asking ChatGPT and modified it to include my own way of trimming/listing the mailbox names (we usually copy from excel so being able to use line breaks to seperate the mailbox names is best). ChatGPT also included a "if not found" clause but that didn't seem to work super well and I removed it.

I ended up with this:

```
# Define the list of display names you want to process
$DisplayNames = @("Mailbox 1
Mailbox2".Trim().Split("`n").Trim())

# Loop through each display name
foreach ($DisplayName in $DisplayNames) {
# Get the user object based on the display name
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter {DisplayName -eq $DisplayName}

# Check if the user was found
if ($User) {
    # Set the Office attribute to $null (clear it)
    Set-ADUser $User -Office $null -Credential $AdminCredentials
}
}
```